# noob: how to show login error message on the same page after php server processes request

Tags: php, javascript

I have a login page.
User first enters information and submits the form.

And I have a php script that will see if the user exists.

```
If( authenticated == true)  
{  
    // I do a redirect  
}  
else  
{  
  // I want to popup an error message on the same page.  
}
```

1) I'm not sure how to show the popup message, 
 I would like to make my div element visible with an error message returned from the server,
I would have to use Ajax, right?
But how?

Or are there alternatives which are just as good.

Comment: +50 for not bothering to learn the basics.

Comment: @fig-gnuton How else is someone going to learn the basics without asking rudimentary questions?

Comment: @David, googling for the thousands of tutorials & articles out there?

Comment: @fig-gnuton The only restrictive criteria for questions on SO is if its of interest to other programmers.  Just going out on a limb here, but I assume there's at least two other student/junior programmers on here.   Otherwise SO's secondary benefit is providing multiple answers to a question instead of one dictated "right way", unfortunately SO doesn't have an official 2nd & 3rd place ranking mechanism for answers.

Comment: @David, sure. Still laziness imo.

Comment: @fig-gnuton Fortunately unlike say IRC, eventually the majority of sutpid questions will be asked and then repeats or similar ones can be closed.

Comment: Actually,  I do agree, laziness it is. But also was hoping to get a bit of guidance from the pros just to point out some hints. Before I do something totally off or unefficient.

Answer (score 2):

if you would use ajax, use it for the whole process. So, no such problems at all. Get response and show it to user.

But as you stated yourself as a newbie, I'd strongly advise you to do it straight and simple way, just to learn how the things are.

As a general rule, a redirect always preferred after POST method request. In some cases one can omit this, but for the login form you would use a session anyway. So, you can start a session, write an error information there and then do `Location:` redirect.

After it, check session for the errors, and then notify user using any method you wish: a div, or a popup or anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the form is posted to the same page, why not just use variables to display the error messages?

```
<?php

if (strlen($_POST['text']) < 5)
{
 $error['text'] = "Too short";
}

?>

<?php

if (isset($error['text']))
{
// Print errors at each form element?
}

?>
```

Hide & show DIVs using Javascript:
http://csscreator.com/node/708

Answer (score 0):

I would put the login page in a separate .HTML that you can run

```
$login = file_get_contents('login.html);
```

and in that markup put <!-- ERROR --> which you can then run a

```
$login = str_replace('<!-- ERROR -->', $error, $login);
```

to insert any text you want and when you're all done

```
print $login;
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest answer is to just place a php if condition where you want the message to appear. No need for ajax.

```
some text above

<?php if (! $authenticated) { echo '<div class="error">'.$your_error_message.'</div>'; } ?>

some text below
```

I don't know what $authenticated in your case means, but make sure it includes a check that there were post variables also, otherwise the error message will show up on the login page in the pre-submitted use case.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly simplest way to

```
function render_auth($errors = false){
?>
   <form action="/someURL">
     <? if($errors) echo $errors ?>
     <label>User name<input name="user_name"/></label><br/>
     <label>Password<input name="user_password" /></label><br/>
     <input type="submit"/>
   </form>
<?
};
```

On first call to the authentication page/controller you'd call render_auth()  then on processing the auth call, if there was an error you'd call it render_auth("Missing password.") or such.

Generally stuff like this is pretty trivial if you're using a Templating system for you're views but if not, this function emulates templating to an extent.

Comment: This is the reason so many people look down on PHP; a horrible mixture of PHP and HTML.

Comment: Unfortunately I totally agree with that statement but figured it would be confusing to try and provide an answer using a real templating system.