# Pass a session from PHP to HTML?

Tags: php, html, forms, session, getmethod

G'day,

This is for my tutorial purpose.

I have 3 files 
1. mlogin.htm - Takes the input from the user (login name and password). The action is set to the next file so the details can be checked.

```
<form id="logIn" name="logIn" method="get" action="mlogin.php">
```

2. mlogin.php - Takes the value from mlogin.htm using GET method. If the details match the details in XML file, the user is redirected to the next file

```
$musername = $_GET['username'];
$mpassword = $_GET['password'];
exit(header('Refresh:5; url=mloginsuccess.htm'));
```

3. mloginsuccess.htm - Displays the menu.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to show the username in the 3rd file so it's something like

```
Welcome, John
```

I do realise that I can do this using a session by changing the 3rd file to a

```
mloginsuccess.php
```

but it MUST be a

```
mloginsuccess.htm
```

I was wondering if this is possible.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: include the files that contain `$musername` and in the page you want to show the user name do `<?php echo 'Welcome, '.$musername;?>` teh page where you are doing the `echo` statement has to be `.php` instead `.html`

Comment: So you mean include mlogin.php in mloginsuccess.htm?
Are you sure it's possible to the include function in a .htm file?

Comment: Unless you use an `AddHandler` to treat `.html` files as `.php` you'll have to rename it.

Comment: you have to change `mloginsuccess.htm` to `mloginsuccess.php`

Comment: and for [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) I mean `<?php include('mlogin.php');?>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Or, use a rewrite rule.

Comment: @Brad Yes, that's another way, however if there are any PHP directives inside the OP's `.html` file, it will ultimately fail.

Comment: I think the OP isn't using any of these options

Comment: @EmilioGort It's best to prepare for the worse.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I don't know how to use an AddHandler. I'm still a beginner.

Comment: @EmilioGort yes but then I'll have to change the 3rd file to a .php which I don't want (well, my tutor)

Comment: @Brad, exactly what I meant.

Comment: Using rewrite rule you change how you see the url, but the file is php

Comment: @callMeJava Just Google "AddHandler" and "treat html as PHP" and you'll find many hits. This is done with your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I have emailed my tutor to ask if I can change the 3rd file to a .php and if yes, then everything is good.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks. I'll have a look now.

Comment: @callMeJava You're welcome. However, certain servers require a bit more than just `AddHandler`. You'll find the right formula, but that's basically how it's done.

Comment: you were right about AddHandler @Fred-ii-, preparing for the worse...lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm using Apache server. 
I, now, have a file `.htaccess` with `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html`
Does this look alright?

Comment: @EmilioGort Yes, it does help to go that route. I rather not use it myself but in certain cases, some must/need to do that.

Comment: @callMeJava You also need to add this `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html` and not just `AddType`

Comment: @callMeJava I think, the case your tutor want to see the webpage in html is because he want you learn how to use rewrite url, I dont see the case to use addHadler

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can I include `AddHandler` and `AddType` in the same `htaccess`file?

Comment: @callMeJava Yes you can.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think rewrite rule is healthier than addHandler? what do you think?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Now I have both `AddType` and `AddHandler` in `.htaccess` file. The contents of the file are now like - 

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm`<br>
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html`

Comment: @Fred-ii- but the username is not still not showing up. The 3rd file is still a .htm :(

Comment: @callMeJava Test to see if the `AddHandler` worked by creating an `.html` file with this inside it `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: @callMeJava And if it does in fact work, well now you need to echo your variable(s)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I made a `test.htm` with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` inside and it worked like a charm! But when I tried the same thing using session on `mloginsuccess.htm`, it didn't work.

Comment: @callMeJava Is `session_start();` inside ALL your pages?

Comment: Sorry those links don't work. 
`mlogin.php` - http://postimg.org/image/q5od7vjyr/
`mloginsuccess.htm` - http://postimg.org/image/rijj057rj/

Comment: @callMeJava You need to echo `$musername` and not `$_SESSION['name']`

Comment: @callMeJava It's ok, I figured the links out. Don't wrap your URLs with brackets, just paste the links.

Comment: @callMeJava I have to call it a night. `$brain="mush";` - Good luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I changed it to `$musername`. If I run the page `mloginsuccess.htm` by itself, "Welcome" shows up and `undefined variable` BUT when run `mlogin.htm` and it redirects to `mloginsuccess.htm`, nothing come up. Not even "Welcome".

Comment: @Fred-ii- Okay. Thanks a lot, anyway. You're awesome :) Take care.

Comment: @Fred-ii- finally got it working! I changed it back to `$_SESSION['name']` and it worked fine! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for a moment that you actually do want to follow your instructions to the letter.  (You don't really want to do this, probably... interpreting requirements, rather than following them exactly, is a key trait of a decent software engineer.)  If your requirement is that you **must** use a static page, you have a couple options for getting data accessible on that page.  All of which require JavaScript.

1. Cookies
2. Query String
3. Anchor Fragment

Basically, you need to set this data in one of these three places so that you can access it with JavaScript from your static HTML page later on.  To set a cookie with PHP, use [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).  To read it with JavaScript, [use `document.cookie`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html), or [one of the many snippets of code to make this easier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5639346/362536).

To set the query string, simply do so in  your redirect:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/mloginsuccess.htm?name=' . urlencode($_GET['username']));
```

See this question for the JavaScript needed to read the query string:  [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979975/362536)

Finally, for the anchor fragment, you can often redirect to it the same way.  (However note that not all browsers are guaranteed to follow the anchor fragment part of the URL!)  To read the anchor fragment, [use `window.location.hash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298513/362536).

I hope that in the end, you will choose to do none of these and keep your auth logic in a sensible place.  Literal interpretation of requirements rarely leads to good code and application design.  At a minimum, you can hack around the URL requirement with a rewrite rule, making whatever.html be an alias to whatever.php.  The client doesn't know or care what is actually running on the server... that's the server's job.  I would tell you how to write a rewrite rule, but you didn't specify which server you are using, so I'll leave that part up to you to Google.

Comment: totally agree with the first paragraph line and beyond..the first paragraph  should be BOLD

Comment: That is some useful information there. I really appreciate you explaining that :)
I'm using an Apache server and I'll have a look how to make an alias.
Again, thanks a ton, good sir.

Comment: @callMeJava No problem.  http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

How can you expect to use a php feature(SESSION) in a file which is not php(.HTML).
However you are allowed to use html inside a php file as php is a template engine and process the html ...refer this for for indepth
[What renders the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194063/php-what-renders-the-html)

just convert your .html to .php and

```
<?php>
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']=$_GET['username']
?>

<html>....<body>welcome <?=$_SESSION['username']?></body>...</html>
```

or however your html tags are.

Comment: Thanks for replying, @Andy. I do realise that but the 3rd files needs to be a .html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use AJAX to load session details. For example, using JQuery,

```
<script>
...
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "load_session.php",
        success: function(uname){
            $("#uname").html(uname);
        }
    });
});
...
</script>
...
Welcome, <span id="uname"></span>
```